# How to change a global variable in python?

Tags: python

I am accessing data from different accounts from an online platform over their API. I have created a class called Account that holds all the information necessary to access this API. I want to be able to set the account (and the necessary info to gain access) each time before I make an API request. I tried to make a function that will set a global variable Acct to the proper account class instance but after I call choose_account(), Acct continues to return '', is there a better way to handle this type of procedure?

```
Acct = ''
def choose_account():
    global Acct
    get = raw_input(r'Adap1, Adap2, Adap3, or Adap4? ')
    if get == 'Adap1':
        Acct = Adap1
    elif get == 'Adap2':
        Acct = Adap2
    elif get == 'Adap3':
        Acct = Adap3
    elif get == 'Adap4':
        Acct = Adap4
    else:
        print ("Please type Adap1, Adap2, Adap3, or Adap4 ")
```

Edit: show Account and Adap1 etc

```
class Account():

    def __init__(self, name, username, password, org_id):
        self.name = name
        self.username = username
        self.password = password
        self.org_id = org_id

    def update_pw(self, pw):
        self.password = pw 

Adap1 = Account('Adap1', 'username', 'password', 'org_id')
```

Comment: where are you setting Adap1,2,3, and 4? They look like they're empty from that code.

Comment: How are you defining `Adap1`, `Adap2`, `Adap3`, `Adap4`? Right now you are treating them as variables in your assignment `Acct = Adap1`, but I suspect you may have wanted to assign `Acct` to the string `'Adap1'`?

Comment: But if that's the case, you could just do `Acct = get if get in ('Adap1', ...) else None`.

Comment: Good point @Kevin but I wan't to set the value of Acct to a class instance of Account so it doesn't work haha

Comment: If you don't mean to have Adap1, Adapt2... be strings and they are indeed defined somewhere else, then you need to either pass them into your choose_account() fuction, or have them be global as well

Comment: I passed Adap1-4 into choose_account() as global but it still doesn't want to change Acct

Comment: I'll just use the function itself rather than having a global variable Acct,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry, but use of global variables in that way is not usually a good way to go. You are probably new to programming, so I don't want you to feel you are being "told off", but it would be *much* more sensible to have the function return a value, and then set the global variable with a statement like

```
Acct = choose_account()
```

In which case your function ought to look more like this (untested code):

```
def choose_acct():
    while True:
        get = raw_input(r'Adap1, Adap2, Adap3, or Adap4? ')
        if get == "Adap1":
            return Adap1
        elif get == "Adap2":
            return Adap2
        elif get == "Adap3":
            return Adap3
        elif get == "Adap4":
            return Adap4
```

Better still, you could consider a data-driven approach to the problem, and define a dictionary like

```
adict = {"Adap1": Adap1, "Adap2": Adap2, "Adap3": Adap3, "Adap4": Adap4}
```

Then your function could read (again, untested)

```
def choose_acct():
    while True:
        get = raw_input(r'Adap1, Adap2, Adap3, or Adap4? ')
        result = adict.get(get, None)
        if result:
            return result
```

As your experience level grows you will start to recognise the difference between good and bad code, but you made a pretty good attempt.

Comment: Thanks, really appreciate the feedback!

Comment: I see this "while True:" line in a lot of code but I am not really sure why it is necessary or what advantage it brings, would you mind explaining that to me a bit?

Comment: Typically, you will see `while True:` when you want a piece of code to never terminate or accompanied by a `break` or `return` inside the loop (like in this case). It's just a way to repeat a set of commands over and over. Some might recommend against using it with a `break` or `return` (and just having the break/return condition be what replaces the `True`), but sometimes `while True:` just results in more readable code, which is a very good thing in my opinion.